# Biometrics sometimes doesn't work in swift

Tags: swift

usually works fine
But very infrequently, biometrics appear and disappear immediately.
doesn't show up at all

I left a log because it is an occasional phenomenon, but the error log is nil

I wonder why the error is getting nil and why this is happening

The code is below

```
let context = LAContext()
let reason = localizedStringFor(key: "", comment: "reason")

context.localizedFallbackTitle = localizedStringFor(key: "", comment: "")

context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) {
    success, error in
            
    var textLog = TextLog()
    let log = Util.getCurrentDate() + " : " + (error?.localizedDescription ?? "nil")"\n"
    textLog.write(log)
            
}
```